# Create a DTM from large corpus

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, nltk

I have a set of texts contained in a list, which I loaded from a csv file

`texts=['this is text1', 'this would be text2', 'here we have text3']`

and I would like to create a document-term matrix, by using *stemmed words*.
I have also stemmed them to have:

`[['text1'], ['would', 'text2'], ['text3']]`

What I would like to do is to create a DTM that counts all the stemmed terms (then  I would need to do some operations on the rows).

For what concerns the unstemmed texts, I am able to make the DTM for short texts, by using the function fn_tdm_df reported [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15899861/efficient-term-document-matrix-with-nltk).
What would be more practical for me, though, is to make a DTM of the stemmed words. Just to be clearer, the output I have from applying "fn_tdm_df":

```js
  be  have  here   is  text1  text2  text3  this   we  would
0  1.0   1.0   1.0  1.0    1.0    1.0    1.0     1  1.0    1.0
1  0.0   0.0   0.0  0.0    0.0    0.0    0.0     1  0.0    0.0
```

First, I do not know why I have only two rows, instead of three. Second, my desired output would be something like:

```
  text1  would  text2  text3
0   1      0      0      0
1   0      1      1      0
2   0      0      0      1
```

I am sorry but I am really desperate on this output. I also tried to export and reimport the stemmed texts on R, but it doesn't encode correctly. I would probably need to handle DataFrames, as for the huge amount of data. What would you suggest me?

----- UPDATE

Using CountVectorizer I am not fully satisfied, as I do not get a tractable matrix in which I can normalize and sum rows/columns easily.

Here is the code I am using, but it is blocking Python (dataset too large). How can I run it efficiently?

```
vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=0., max_df=1.0)
X = vect.fit_transform(texts)
print(pd.DataFrame(X.A, columns=vect.get_feature_names()).to_string())
df = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray().transpose(), index = vect.get_feature_names())
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you use `sklearn`? The `CountVectorizer()` method **converts a collection of text documents to a matrix of token counts**. What's more it gives a sparse representation of the counts using `scipy`.

You can either give your raw entries to the method or preprocess it as you have done (stemming + stop words).

Check this out : [CountVectorizer()](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html)

Comment: That is a good idea, indeed. I tried, but it gave me a "confusing" output, that is, I would like to have a tractable matrix in which I can sum columns and create new of them. That is the code I am implementing following your hint (see the edited post).

Comment: the `fit_transform()` method returns an `array`. You can transform it to a `DataFrame` using pandas. Then you'll be able to do what ever you want with your data.

Comment: That is fine, indeed. However, Python is blocking it while running my code (above), that coincides with what you suggested. Any hint on how to make it run smoothly?

Comment: Where does it block ? Did you try to reduce the number of words you have ? Use `stop_words = 'english' ` as a parameter of your `CountVectorizer`. See if it does not prune the dataset enough first.

Comment: I stem and remove punctuation before that. It blocks when computing df, in the last line. I do the stemming before the lines of code posted. How can I reduce a bit the matrix?

Comment: Use `stop_words = 'english`` in your `CountVectorizer`. It takes off `stop words` encountered in the english language. It seems that you did not take them off

Comment: I am sorry I do not have enough reputation to chat, but it does not work at all. There is no punctuation, and it blocks when doing last line.

Comment: Use this instead `vect = CountVectorizer(min_df=0., max_df=1.0, stop_words='english')`

Comment: Unfortunately it crashes. I had to restart my computer.